# Android Studio Chipmunk not showing android device for flutter app installation

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, chipmunk

I have updated to android studio chipmunk, I created a sample flutter project where my android device is not showing in the flutter tab to install the flutter app. I am able to run a sample android project. I tried re-installing chipmunk and SDK as fresh but it doesn't help me.
[image]

Comment: so you are trying with external device and its not showing?

Comment: yes, i tried an external device which I have instead of an emulator.

Comment: so I assume the emulator works fine and the external didn't even though you turned on the developer mode and USB debugging in your android phone?

Comment: Can you please run from your terminal (making sure that flutter is added to your path)
`flutter doctor -v` and
`adb devices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows 10 you have to add adb software path in environment variables path

E:<SDK_Path>/platform-tools/
[image]

after run 2 cmd for testing purpose  :

1. adb devices
2. flutter devices

[image: cmd]